# No Action works after Enabling ServerSocket in JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, serversocket

I have created a Server Socket and enabled it to listen to incoming streams.But after enabling the connection it should display a dialog Box showing message "Server Started" ,but it does not appear . I have noticed that after enabling the socket no code after that works. I have tried searching a lot about this but seem to find no suitable answer.Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Server
{
public Server(int i1) throws Exception{

    ServerSocket MySock=new ServerSocket(i1);//opening server socket
    Socket Sock=MySock.accept();//listening to client enabled 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server Started");
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
    new Server(2005);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ServerSocket.accept()` is [blocks until a connection is made.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept--).

So the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...)` will not be executed until someone is connecting to the serversocket.

Here is a solution that handles the `ServerSocket` in a separate thread

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Server
{
    public Server(int i1) throws Exception{

        Runnable serverTask = () -> {

            try {
                ServerSocket MySock=new ServerSocket(i1);//opening server socket

                while (true) {
                    Socket Sock=MySock.accept();//listening to client enabled
                    System.out.println("Accept from " + Sock.getInetAddress());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            }

        };

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.submit(serverTask);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server Started");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Server(2005);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you did here is coded the dialog before enabling a connection but the problem is no code works after MySock.accept() is started. Suppose I want to close this server by using MySock.close() using JButton . In this case I noticed that the JButton was performing no action

Comment: Ok, you need to put the serversocket in a separate thread. I will update the answer with an example